# Menu drop down covers contents of page in Mobile view

Tags: menus, css, dropdown

Hi folks I want to try fix my menu. When on a mobile device I click the burger menu. Its expands but it partially coves up the contents of my pages or posts.
Is there a workaround for this ?[image]

The address is [www.boat-renovation.com](http://www.boat-renovation.com)

Comment: Well... ...what is the alternative behaviour you're after?  Do you want it to expand into place and push content down, do you want it to fill the whole screen?  And it's 99%  likely this is entirely down to CSS and you changing the position value on the parent container for the navigation. It's either `fixed` or `absolute` right now, so not in the flow the document, and what you're looking for is `relative` positioning. Unless if you want it to grow fully and cover the content completely, then it's a sizing and positing issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.